# How to avoid partial file if exception thrown during json dump?

Tags: python, json, exception, file-handling

The following code throws

> TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable

which I know how to resolve.  However my real question is how to cleanly structure the code to avoid a partial file if any exception occurs in [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage).

```
import datetime
import json

def save(data):
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)

data = dict(sometime=datetime.datetime.now())
save(data)
```

The above code throws an exception and results in a partial file like:

```
{"sometime":
```

Should I `dumps` to a string first in a `try/except`?  If so are there any memory implications to be aware of? Or delete the file in an except block?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`try/except`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) block like:

#### Code:

```
def save_json(data, filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
    except:
        try:
            os.unlink(filename)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
```

and if you want to preserve the exception:

```
def save_json(data, filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
    except:
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            os.unlink(filename)
        raise
```

#### Test Code:

```
import datetime
import json
import os

data = dict(sometime=datetime.datetime.now())
save_json(data, 'data.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether your JSON data is under your control or from unknown source. If it’s from somewhere you can’t predict, use  `try...except...` block. Otherwise, fix your program to make it always available to serialize.